# Left and right floated boxes wider than their container

Tags: css, css-float

Let's see:

Container box is 920px, left box is 600px, right box width dinamically changing between 200px and 400px. As we know in basic situation if two floated box wider than their container the lastest one breaks into a new line.

I tried to solve it with negative leftmargin on right box and it works fine. (buggy on IE6 but it does not matter.)

Is negative margin good or can I avoid annoying float box breaking in other way? (i don't want to use absolute positioning.)

Comment: Negative margin is never good. How can a margin be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative left margin is great. I use it lots of time to align to the center `left:50%; margin-left: -250px; // width == 500px;` so don't worry you can use it without a problem.

Also ppl use it for lot's of small things. It's not uncommon for sites to have elements with negative margins.

Even here in Stackoverflow if you look at the CSS you can find negative margins.